# How to restrict template parameter to pointer or random access iterator only?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert

Is there a way to restrict the parameter type of a template function to only pointers or random-access iterators?

Say I am developing a sorting function which works only with random accessible containers. I am looking for a way to throw a compile-time error if the user passes a non-random-access iterator.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

template <class Iterator> void mySort(Iterator begin, Iterator end){

    /*The below condition must be true if the 'Iterator' type is a pointer 
    or if it is of Category random_access_iterator_tag. How to make such check?*/
    static_assert(some condition, "The mySort() function only accepts random access iterators or raw pointers to an array.\n");

    for (Iterator it = begin; it != end; ++it){
        /*Some kind of sorting is performed here, which 
        uses arithmetic operators + and - in the iterator type. */
    }
}
```

I know that to check if a type is a pointer I could use `std::is_pointer<Iterator>::value` and to check if the iterator is random access I could use `std::is_same<std::random_access_iterator_tag, Iterator::iterator_category>::value`.

The first problem is that both checks should be OR'd inside the same `static_assert()`, otherwise if either one was matched, the other would not.

The second problem is that the random access check would fail if the function was to be called called in such a way: `mySort<int*>(...)`. This obviously happens since `int*` does not have the `::iterator_category` definition.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?
I also know the compiler would automatically throw errors for the attempt of using arithmetic operators with non-random-access iterators, but I would like to display a more comprehensive error message through `static_assert()`.

As a follow up question. In the case 'Iterator' is a pointer type, is there a way to assert it is of a primitive type (non `struct`/`class`)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see how the first "problem" is a problem. Could you explain?

Comment: I was referring to the fact that if I was to use two static_asserts (which was my first thought), one for each check, one would fail.
More precisely, asserting in the following way:
`static_assert(std::is_same<std::random_access_iterator_tag, Iterator::iterator_category>::value, "")`
_and_
`static_assert(std::is_pointer<Iterator>::value, "")`
would cause the below calls to fail (which I would not like them to):
`mySort<int*>(...)`
`mySort<std::vector<int>::iterator>(...)`
Nevertheless, using Dieter's solution this is obviously no longer a problem! `std::iterator_traits` does the job!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use iterator traits:

```
static_assert(
    std::is_same<std::random_access_iterator_tag,
                 typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category>::value,
    "The mySort() function only accepts random access iterators or raw pointers to an array.\n");
```

Comment: You are better off using is_convertible instead of is_same, as what will happen with http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3884.pdf is still unknown.

Comment: +1 I have written an answer using SFINAE and partial specialization, but this is obviously the way to go: The standard library provides std::iterator_traits just for this purpose. Don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: @Nevin 'is_convertible' might be an option, but the contiguous memory is no issue, here.

Comment: Yes, but the random_access_iterator tag may change to contiguous_iterator_tag for pointers, vector/string iterators, etc.

Comment: @Nevin I hope, not ! (An additional contiguous_iterator_tag would be fine)

Comment: @ DieterLücking: As I am the author of that paper, your feedback is noted and seriously being considered.  (The only way to not break backwards compatibility is to introduce a separate trait that contains the tag, but that discussion is beyond the question posed here by the OP.)